# How to print header on every page from AG Grid React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Dealing with an AG Grid in React typescript app and I need a way to implement print functionality where AG Grid Header will be printed on every print page, because table has a lot of data and it is printed on several print pages.
With DOMLayout I got **page-break-inside: avoid** but I need something like **display: table-header-group** for my header.
I tried solution with transform AG Grid to standard table (table,thead,tbody,tr... tags) with javascript code, but I did not success because of DOM complexity of AG Grid.

**If you have code for transforming AG Grid to standard table it could help me too**.

Solution that convert AG Grid to PDF can not help me, because on the page in React app I have several tables and they need to be printed together one after the other continuously.

**Example of AG-Grid DOM which needs to be transformed to table tag:**
https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/printing/for-print-complex/packages/vanilla/index.html

Comment: share your code

Comment: Code is not so important in this case, but here you can see live example of table in ag-grid react app printing with DOMLayout to "print": https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/printing/#example-for-print-complex

Comment: ask this question from @dai

Comment: he answered right now there https://stackoverflow.com/q/71185411/17226535